# Copy/set a single byte in a Memory<byte>

Tags: c#, resharper, c#-7.2

I'm starting out with `System.Buffers.MemoryPool<T>` and `System.Memory<T>` in C#, looking to reduce allocations for byte arrays.

I have a bunch of bytes and byte arrays that I need to copy to a single byte array (for use in a method that only works with `byte[]`, not `Span`/`Memory`). I'm doing something like this:

```
byte aByte = 0x01;
byte[] aByteArray = { 0x02, 0x03, 0x04 };
byte[] anotherByteArray = { 0x05, 0x06, 0x07 };

using (var buffer = MemoryPool<byte>.Shared.Rent(7))
{
    Span<byte> target;

    target = buffer.Memory.Slice(0, aByteArray.Length).Span;
    aByteArray.CopyTo(target);

    target = buffer.Memory.Slice(aByteArray.Length, anotherByteArray.Length).Span;
    aByteArray.CopyTo(target);

    // How to copy a single byte?
}
```

So, I've figured out how to copy byte arrays to the buffer, but can't figure out how to set a single byte. I tried `buffer.Memory.Span[0] = aByte`, but `Span` has no setter.

Comment: `buffer.Memory.Span[0] = aByte;` works for me.

Comment: Funny, i checked just the documentation for the indexer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1.item?view=netcore-2.2#System_Span_1_Item_System_Int32_. It says the indexer can be used to get and set, but then the declaration of the indexer shows that it only has a getter. Perhaps newer versions of .NET Core have setter, whereas older don't. I have no idea...

Comment: Check that you don't somehow end up with a IReadOnlyMemory/IReadOnlySpan

Comment: @KevinGosse nope, it's a `Span<byte>`, the issue is it's get-only

Comment: @elgonzo hmm, it seems it *does* work when targetting .NET Core 2.1, but *not* when targetting .NET Standard 2.0. Which is very dissapointing, as I need to target both .NET Core and .NET Framework :/

Comment: Getter is ref returning, so you do not need a setter, and you can not define setter for ref returning property. Also I do not have any problem using it in .NET Framework or .NET Core. If you have any compilation error trying to use it, then you should add it into the question.

Comment: @PetSerAl gah, you're right - there's no error at compile time, just shown in Visual Studio... ReSharper has let me known again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading @PetSerAl's comment I checked, and actually there wasn't a compile-time error - only a warning shown in Visual Studio. ReSharper has let me donw here with what is presumably a bug.

I should have thought to check this, as ReSharper has let me down plenty times before with new'ish C# functionality, such as `Span<T>` and `Memory<T>` :/